# Java method for objects cast possibility

Tags: java, class, casting

Is is possible to check whether given Object item can be casted to some class? Is there any method which doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: Are you referring to the `instanceof` operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [`Class.isInstance(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) and the related [`Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

Example:

```
Object x = "foo";
Integer.class.isInstance(x); // => false
Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(x.getClass()); // => false
```

---

**Edit**: You said "method" so I assumed you meant an API method, but if you know the types at compile-time then you can simply use

```
x instanceof Integer // => false
```

(see also [What is the 'instanceof' operator used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for))