# How does RandomAccess interface works internally?

Tags: java

As per my understanding, this RandomAccess interface provides an ability to retrieve data in constant time. How this functionality is achieved? Is there any hashing technique?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `RandomAccess` is a marker interface. It does not provide or do anything by itself. It's used to indicate that the class that implements it, has the specified capability - it's up to the class to provide this capability, not the `RandomAccess` interface. This has nothing at all to do with hashing.

Comment: It doesn't work internally at all. It only provides a contract. How it works internally in each case is up to the various implementations.

Comment: It may help you to realize that interfaces do not provide actual implementations by looking at the source code of `RandomAccess`, it is: `public interface RandomAccess { }`, thats it. It is empty, just a marker interface.

Comment: I know all the above described concepts.. i had even checked the source code of Arraylist and the RandomAccess interface. My doubt is .. if the RandomAccess interface is marker , will the jvm give the ability for the implemented classes to access elements in constant time?

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is wrong. `RandomAccess` may provide a *promise* but it doesn’t provide any ability. Providing the ability is up to the implementing class. Actually `RandomAccess` doesn’t “work internally” in any sense of the expression, it has no functionality whatsoever.

In [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) it called *an indication*, not a promise:

> Marker interface used by `List` implementations to indicate that they
>   support fast (generally constant time) random access.

The classes implementing `RandomAccess` generally provide constant time access by storing their contents in an array. Array lookup takes constant time. (Classes implementing the interface include `ArrayList`, `AttributeList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, `RoleList`, `RoleUnresolvedList`, `Stack` and `Vector` according to the documentation. Surely also some third-party classes implement it too.)

Edit: Fast access in arrays relies on the hardware. The computer can access any memory cell (storage cell) in constant time. Array elements are laid out in consecutive memory cells. So if you know that an array is laid out from address 54321 and you need to access the array element at index 35, you add those two numbers and know the element is at memory address 54356 (I am ignoring the slight complication in that the word size is often 8 bytes and addresses have granularity of 1 byte). The principle is the same whether the JVM is interpreting byte code or the method has been compiled to native machine code thus bypasses the JVM. Your search engine should lead to a better explanation than the one I am giving here.

It’s quite general for interfaces they they don’t have any internal working but leave this to the classes implementing the interface (as has been said, since Java 8 and 9 the situation has become more blurred, but in this respect `RandomAccess` still keeps the classical design). It’s the job of an interface to *specify* a behaviour and that of the implementing class/es to *provide* it.

Edit:

> From the documentation, "The primary purpose of this interface is to
>   allow generic algorithms to alter their behavior to provide good
>   performance when applied to either random or sequential access lists".
>   Why it is mentioned as algorithms here?

“Generic algortithms” refers to algorithms that you and I write that work with lists that may or may not have fast element access (may or may not implement `RandomAccess`). So you may write for example:

```
public void yourMethod(List<String> param) {
     if (param instanceof RandomAccess) {
          // do your work relying on fast element access
     } else {
         // do your work in some other way that doesn’t depend on fast element access
         // for example by iterating sequentially through the list
         // or copying the elements to a faster list implementation first.
     }
}
```

So no, it has nothing to do with different JVM implementations.

Comment: 'The classes implementing RandomAccess generally provide constant time access by storing their contents in an array. Array lookup takes constant time.'  -  can you please explain this in detail. Is the jvm responsible for the above mentioned operation?

Comment: From the documentation, "The primary purpose of this interface is to allow generic algorithms to alter their behavior to provide good performance when applied to either random or sequential access lists".   Why it is mentioned as algorithms here? Does it vary based on different jvm implementation ? (Like hotspot jvm). Can you please explain this in detail.

Answer (score 3):

`RandomAccess` is a *marker interface*. It is an interface with no methods. Apart from that an interface *generally* does not have any functionality in it <sup>1</sup>. It is upto the implementing classes to provide random access functionality.

Have a look at

[Why does ArrayList implement RandomAccess Interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869993/why-does-arraylist-implement-randomaccess-interface/20870007)

[What is the use of marker interfaces in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995198/what-is-the-use-of-marker-interfaces-in-java)

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes. An interface can have default methods that has some logic. But this was added only from Java 8 to enable adding new methods to an interface without breaking the implementing classes. An interface is only for providing or declaring the contract that the implementing class has to fulfil.

Comment: 'Apart from that an interface generally does not have any functionality in it 1. It is upto the implementing classes to provide random access functionality.'.  Arraylist implements RandomAccess but it does not have any implementation as this is a marker interface. So my doubt is.. will the jvm be the one who provides implementation to this interface?

Comment: If so, for retrieving elements in constant time what sort of technique it would be using? Will it be hashing technique?

Comment: `ArrayList` is not an interface - it is a class. The way it offers O(1) access is dependent on the implementation. Usually it is an array as Ole's answer points out