# When does instanceof return FALSE?

Tags: java, instanceof

I know that instanceof returns TRUE when an object is an instance of a particular class. For instance:

```
B extends A
C extends A

B b = new B();
C c = new C();

b instanceof A // returns TRUE
```

So far so good, so let's enter something that would seem like it should return false:

```
c instanceof B // won't compile (error: inconvertible types)
```

This doesn't compile, which makes sense because it allows an oversight to be caught at compile time. But, when DOES instanceof actually return false? It seems the only two options are TRUE and ERROR. The only exception I can think of is this:

```
null instanceof A // returns FALSE
```

But by the same logic as above, it would seem this should be caught at compile time as well.

What am I missing here? Are true / error the only practical options, or is it possible to actually return false in a more meaningful way, aside from when null is given as a reference variable?

Comment: That's safaris spell checker. Consider the above pseudo code. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the 'instanceof' operator used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for)

Comment: `(Object)c instanceof B` will compile. The reason `c instanceof B` doesn't compile is the compiler can determine statically that a reference to a `C` can never be a `B`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example that evaluates to false:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

A a = new A();
a instanceof B   // false
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/cQltqE.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers:  any time either the expression on the left, or the type on the right, is an interface, then `instanceof` *could* be true, so the compiler has to allow it.  So it's easy to come up with examples where it would be false.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another example that returns false

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    checkType("");
}

static <T> void checkType(T sometype) {
    System.out.println(sometype instanceof A);
}

static class A {}
```

It's really only useful when trying to compare (and then cast) to a more specific type.

In your example,

```
c instanceof A
```

doesn't make sense since the type `C` is not in the inheritance hierarchy of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

```
B extends A
C extends A

B b = new B();
C c = new C();

b instanceof A // returns TRUE
myMethod(b); // has TRUE and then FALSE
myMethod(c); // has FALSE and then TRUE

void myMethod(A a){
  if(a instanceof B){System.out.println("This is a B");}//first statement
  if(a instanceof C){System.out.println("This is a C");}//second statement
}
```

In call of `myMethod(b)`, if evaluation in second statement of this method will be **FALSE** and will print *This is a B*. However in call of `myMethod(c)` if evaluation in first statement of this method will be **FALSE** and will print *This is a C*