# How do I check the type of a subclass?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I want to check the type of a subclass in Java. Here's the pseudocode I want to achieve:

```
public class Brown { ... }
class Poo extends Brown { ... }
class Brownie extends Brown { ... }
...

ArrayList<Brown> brownThings = new ArrayList<Brown>();
...

for (Brown i: brownThings)
    // if i is a brownie eat
    // else dispose of
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use instanceof key word

```
if (i instanceof Brownie ) {
    // do something
  }
```

That exactly checks the instance type.

Comment: I think that it wanna check if it is a Brownie not a Poo.

Comment: You need not to check, everything is `Brownie`  in that list then :), Since every `Child` is `Parent`

Comment: Everything in the list is Brown not Brownie (a subclass of Brown)

Comment: Oops ..Ooops, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `instaceof` operator. For example:

```
if (i instanceof Brownie) {
  eat(i);
} else {
  dispose(i);
}
```

`instaceof` opertaor check if the type of an object is an instance of a class or a class that extends or implements the specified type.

You can read more in [Java tutorial, operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html). Also see question [What is the instaceof operator used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for).

Answer (score 0):

```
instanceof can handle that just fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
for (Brown i: brownThings) {
    if (i instanceof Brownie) {
        //eat
    }
}
```