# Java get runtime class of this?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, runtime

Say I have the following object hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    ...
}

public class Canine extends Animal {
    ...
}

public class Feline extends Animal {
    ...
}

public class Dog extends Canine {
    ...
}

public class Wolf extends Canine {
    ...
}

public class Leopard extends Feline {
    ...
}
```

Let's say the `Animal` class has a final method that needs to take different actions depending on what the object's runtime type/class is:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    // Lots of stuff blah blah blah

    public final makeNoise() {
        // If we're a Dog, then System.out.println("Woof!");
        // Else if we're a Wolf, then System.out.println("Gggrrrrr!");
        // etc.
    }
}
```

**Here's the kicker:** I *know* that best practices and OOP would have me write `makeNoise()` to be an abstract method, and then just implement a different version in each subclass. **However**, for reasons outside the scope of this question, I can't do that.

So, barring best OOP practices, how can I tell - from inside the parent `makeNoise()` method - what our runtime class is?

Comment: `public final makeNoise()` has no return type!

Comment: Just curious, why aren't you just doing this OOP style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `instanceof` operator: [What is the 'instanceof' operator used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for)

Bear in mind that doing things the way you're asking will require `Animal` to know about all of its subclasses (direct and otherwise). This clearly does not scale and invites maintenance problems.

Comment: The method should be overridden in the necessary classes instead of using `instanceof` per subclass.

Comment: Ok, very odd request. Well, `instanceof` can do it assuming `Dog` and the other classes (`Worlf`, `Leopard`, etc.) don't have subclasses as well, otherwise it might be better using `this.getClass().equals(Dog.class)` and on...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: A complete nightmare for sure. But that's what the OP is asking...

Comment: Thanks all - I'm going with Luiggi's suggestion because there are several levels of inheritance going on here. **Trust me**, this isn't how I want to code...

Comment: @TotesMcGotes we're all curious of the constraint that is disallowing you from using OO concepts in an OO language. Care to share?

Answer (score 3):

To get the runtime class use getClass().  It will return the sub-class even though the code is in the super-class.

```
this.getClass()
```