# Different objects in array

Tags: java, arrays, object

Good time of the day to anybody reading,

I would like to ask if the following situation is possible to do in Java:

What do I want to do - create a 2D array which can have different objects in it (i.e. in [0][2] I would like to have PreRoom object, in [0][3] - Room object) and would like these object to be accessible (obviously).

How am I doing this?

1) Declare 2D array of Object type:

```
Object[][] map = new Object[151][151];
```

2) Create an object:

```
map[0][2] = new PreRoom(r, true);
```

3) But after this I'm unable to use any method of PreRoom/get any its property, i.e. unable to do:

```
map[0][2].x;
//or
map[0][2].getR;
```

Am I doing this wrong? Or it's impossible to do and therefore the only solution is to create a unified object for current 2?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: solution found, thanks for the replies.

Comment: Either explicitly cast it, or if you can't rely on the type of the object, then an [instanceof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for) check may be of benefit to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `Object[][] map = new Object[151][151];` So anything you store in it will be an Object (Obviously), so how does it know that your Object in `map[0][2]` is of `PreRoom`? You will need to cast it as such so you can use any methods of `PreRoom`

```
((PreRoom)map[0][2]).methodName();
```

Be careful in future if you are storing numerous types in your `map`. You may find `instanceof` useful if you ever need to iterate through your map not knowing which values are of what.

For example;

```
if(map[x][y] instanceof PreRoom) {
   //map[x][y] is an instance of your PreRoom class
   PreRoom preRoomObj = (PreRoom) map[x][y];
}
```

Comment: Not the first to answer, but for anyone else coming here will be definitely the best answer, thanks.

Comment: No worries :) If you think it answered your question (or any of the other answers for that matter) please mark one as correct :)

Comment: Was unable to do it in first 10 min-s after posting:)

Answer (score 1):

You can define an interface or abstract class that will be implemented/inheritedd by both PreRoom and Room class.

Then you array could be something like

```
<InterfaceName/AbstractClassName>[] = new <InterfaceName/AbstractClassName>[151][151];
```

You interface or base class should declare the common methods and variable.

Comment: While I realize this doesn't technically answer the question, this is what you should do if you want to keep your code maintainable and well structured.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to explicitly type cast to call the methods on that object

```
((PreRoom)map[0][2]).x
```