# Which keyword in helps to determine subclass?

Tags: java, subclass, instanceof

```
obj instanceof Arrays
```

would help be know if `obj` is instance of `Arrays`, but what i want to know if what operator to use to find if `obj` is a subclass of `Arrays` ?

Assume class Animal is super class of Dog.

```
Dog d = new Dog().
```

if (`dog` "which operator ? " `Animal`) would result in `true` ?

Comment: At compile time, you already have this information. At runtime, you'd have `Class` objects for each type. Is that what you want/are working with?

Comment: Just got an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for

Comment: Do you mean if _obj is an **instance of a subclass** of `Arrays`_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instanceof` will return true for subclasses as well. An instance of `Dog` is also an instance of `Animal`.

Answer (score 2):

See [`isAssignableFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

```
Animal.class.isAssignableFrom(dog.getClass())
```

will return you `true` if `Dog` is child of `Animal` (either extends or implements)

this will help you if you have type determined at runtime, if it is fixed to check against type then you can use `instanceof` operator

also while using this method make sure to handle `null`

Comment: If you want to make sure that dog's class is exclusively a child class of `Animal` then you want to say `Animal.class.isAssignableFrom(dog.getClass()) && !dog.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Animal.class)`

Comment: `isAssignableFrom()` is neither a keyword nor an operator. Also, what you've written is mostly equivalent to `dog instanceof Animal` - the exception being if `dog` is `null`, which, according to the question, it's not

Answer (score 1):

Jigar's solution is probably best, but you could probably do it this way too:

```
dog instanceof Animal && !dog.getClass().equals(Animal.class)
```

This will only return true if `dog`'s class is a child of `Animal` but is not a base-level `Animal` instance.