# Get concrete class of interface field using Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class which has an interface as member

```
Class A {
    IProp property;
}
```

At runtime we assign property with one of the concrete classes implementing `IProp`. 
Say,

```
A a = new A();
a.property = new IPropImpl();
```

Now if I have object `a`, I get the fields using reflection :

```
Field[] fields = a.getDeclaredFields();
```

But for field `property`, the type is returned as `IProp`. I want to get the concrete type which was assigned to it. ( There maybe multiple concrete types. I want to get the one which is assigned to the field).

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: You can use `instanceOf` on the field to test which is the  implementation. I'm afraid that the only way to do that directly is changing `property` type to the implementation, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getDeclaredFields()` (or any other method of [`java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for that matter) returns the compile-time data that's available for the **class** - it cannot return data based on a specific **instance** you're using.

What you could do is simply retrieve the instance you're holding and query its type:

```
System.out.println(a.property.getClass());
```

EDIT:

To address the comments, this can also be done by reflection, but would still have to address a specific instance:

```
for (Field f : a.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    Class<?> cls = f.get(a).getClass();
    System.out.println
        (f.getName() + " is set with a concrete class of " + cls.getName());
}
```

Comment: How will this work if I don't know what the fields are? Say I don't know that a has a field called property. This is why I went with reflection.

Comment: Worked brilliantly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [instanceOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for) on the field to test which is the implementation. I'm afraid that the only way to do that directly is changing property type to the implementation, which is not what you want.

The code would be:

```
IProp property = null;
try {
    property = (IProp) A.class.getDeclaredField("property").get(a);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException
        | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(property instanceof IPropImpl){
    //do something
}else if(property instanceof IPropImpl2){
    //do something else
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to get programmatically all implementing classes of a specific interface which are already instantiated you can do it with the [Reflection library](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/)

```
new Reflections("my.package").getSubTypesOf(MyInterface.class)
```

Else if you are using Eclipse click on the interface name, `IProp`, and press `CTRL + T`. It will show all implementing classes for the interface in workspace.

Comment: Problem with this approach is I really don't know what classes implement the interface. Is there any way to get the list of classes implementing a particular interface ?