# Enhanced FoR loop in an Array based on classes in Java

Tags: java

the thing I would like to know is how to write an enhanced for loop for an array based on the class of the object in the array.  I understand how to do a for loop based on index number like if it's odd or even but I'm looking for based on class.  Example:

```
Array[] Kind = new Array[3];
Kind[0] = new Fruit(xxx,yyy,zzz)
Kind[1] = new Veg(xxx,yyy,zzz)
Kind[2] = new Fruit(xxx,yyy,zzz)
Kind[3] = new Veg(xxx,yyy,zzz)
```

Fruit and Veg classes are created and extended from the Kind class.  I need to write a FOR loop that out puts something for Fruit and something different for Veg.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for

Comment: Erm... fruit and veg should know how to deal with this. In general, if you're checking instanceof then something has gone wrong with your OO design.

Comment: `Kind` is a class?  The way you wrote it, `Array` is your class and `Kind` is a variable name.  Also, you allocated only 3 elements in your array and you're trying to assign to 4, so you will get an out-of-bounds exception.  Maybe you mean `Kind[] array = new Kind[4];` and then set `array[0] = ` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to fix your program: rather than declaring an array of arrays `Array[]`, declare an array of base classes `Kind`, like this:

```
Kind[] kind = new Kind[4];
kind[0] = new Fruit(xxx,yyy,zzz);
kind[1] = new Veg(xxx,yyy,zzz);
kind[2] = new Fruit(xxx,yyy,zzz);
kind[3] = new Veg(xxx,yyy,zzz);
```

Now if you would like to print different things for `Fruit` and `Veg` subclasses of `Kind`, override `toString` of the two classes as needed. This would let you go through instances of your base class `Kind`, and printing would be dispatched to the method in the appropriate class:

```
public class Fruit extends Kind {
    @Override
    public string toString() {
        return "Fruit "+ ... // Fill in the text that you wish to print
    }
}
public class Veg extends Kind {
    @Override
    public string toString() {
        return "Veg "+ ... // Fill in the text that you wish to print
    }
}
```

Printing can be done like this:

```
for (Kind item : kind) {
    System.out.println(item.toString());
}
```

The call of `toString()` above is optional - you can call `System.out.println(item);` as well. I added the call of `toString()` to show that there is no "magic" in there.

Comment: You've reproduced the OP's error of initializing the array to only hold 3 objects instead of the 4 given.

Comment: @Blazto Not when you're initializing. You initialize to the length. [3] is 3 objects at [0],[1],[2].