# How do i set the value to be integer?

Tags: java, casting, jtable

is it possible for the cell to be input with integer only? This is my code.

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    return col == 3;
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    data[row][col] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question; could you please rephrase it? What is the type of `data`?

Comment: You can add a validation at the begging of the `setValueAt` method.

Comment: The question is missing context. It seems you try to inherit from some GUI-Table-class, maybe JTable or implementing maybe TableModel? Without this context nobody can help you, as we all can only guess what's the problem.

Comment: Create a model to supply your table with. See -> [The Java™ Tutorials: Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use **instanceof** to check if object is of type Integer. ([Usage Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for))

If String is going to be sent and you want to check if it is integer, use

> Integer.parseInt((String)value)

It throws an exception when the value is not parsable or value is not of type String. You can implement your control accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col){

    if(!isIntegerValue(value)) {
        throw new Exceoption("not integer value");
    }

    data[row][col]=value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}

private boolean isIntegerValue(Object value) {
    return value instanceof Integer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, when i type integer values, there is an error. It says :java.lang.Exception: Not integer value

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of `value` (`value instanceof Integer`) and throw an Exception in case it is not integer. Unless you do not want to use some kind of wrapper, there is no chance to ensure the type of `value` at compile time, while you have to keep the method's header.