# Inheritance and 'Instanceof' testing result

Tags: java

I'm studying 'instanceof' java, but I couldn't understand 'instanceof' clearly, I thought below answer would be true and false, but result is both true. Could you explain why this result happen? As I know, when A is child of B (Parent), and a instanceof B is 'false' but result is different with what I thought.

```
class Car{
    String color;
    int door;       
}

class FireEngine extends Car{
    void water(){
        System.out.println("water");
    }
}

public class Operator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new FireEngine();
        FireEngine fireCar = new FireEngine();

        System.out.println(car instanceof FireEngine);
        System.out.println(fireCar instanceof Car);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between the type of a variable and the type of an object. Variable `car` has type `Car`, but its value is type `FireEngine`. Imagine that the variable is a bottle, a bottle can hold liquids. Beer is a liquid therefore you can put it in a bottle. If you do so, `bottle instanceof Beer` will return true, even if the bottle isn't labelled as beer bottle.

Comment: A FireEngine is a car and a FireEngine is a FireEngine. It's about the object instantiated, not about how the variable is defined.

Comment: Just my two cents: in real code, when using `instanceof`, it is 95% of the times a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). It is 100% fine to use it for learning purposes and to understand typing and polymorphism, but in the future, when you actually write code, and have to use `instanceof` - it should raise a red flag that indicates "something in here is probably poorly designed".

Answer (score 7):

### Declaration != Value

You declare `car` as an Car, but the Value is an `FireEngine`.

`instanceof` works based on *values*, not on the *declarations* of their variables!!!

Shortening may help to understand:

```
System.out.println(new FireEngine() instanceof FireEngine);  // true
System.out.println(new FireEngine() instanceof Car);         // true
```

Answer (score 2):

The output of `instanceof` depends on the runtime type of the variable whose type you are testing. The compile time type of the variable doesn't matter (as long as it is possible that `x instanceof` Y will return true for some value of `x`, otherwise the expression won't pass compilation).

Both `car` and `fireCar` hold instances of `FireEngine` in your code. And since `FireEngine` is a kind of a `Car`, both `car` and `fireCar` are `instanceof` both `Car` and `FireEngine`, so your code prints `true` and `true`.

Answer (score 1):

> Implementation of the Instanceof operator. Returns a Boolean if the Object parameter (which can be an expression) is an instance of a class type.
>
> Input 1: An object or Expression returning an object.
>
> Input 2: A Class or an Expression returning a Class
> Returns: A Boolean that is the result of testing the object against the Class.

For more information please go throught the javadocs @ http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/javadoc/com/bea/p13n/expression/operator/Instanceof.html

For more detailed explanation with examples please go through the following web page : http://mindprod.com/jgloss/instanceof.html

Answer (score 1):

> In Java there are two types of bindings: **static** (the reference type)
>   and **dynamic** (the object type).

In your case:

```
 Car car = new FireEngine();
```

Car is the static type and FireEngine is dynamic type. It means, you are actually working with a FireEngine (the **object** type). You can imagine Car as a special pointer with a car shape pointing to the real object that is your awesome FireEngine. If you read 'instanceof' you can understand it, this method tell you if an **object** is an instance of a class, not the reference. So the compiler will see: FireEngine (car) instanceOf FireEngine? Of course, let's return a true!

You can have a look to this post also: [What is the 'instanceof' operator used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for])

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
As I know, when A is child of B (Parent), 
and a instanceof B is 'false' but result is different with what I thought.
```

is not correct. `instanceof` does not check for the child, it tests for the parent.