# "If the previous activity was ... do something"

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I'm developping an Android Application but I'm blocked. I'm searching for a condition like this :

```
if the previous activity was ...{
       *do something*
}
```

I want to fill an Arraylist of Strings only if the String comes from the previous activity.

Thank you in advance for your answers !

V.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Give your current action a name and store it as your last action.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android   this?

Comment: Jave `instanceof`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313605/603270

Comment: Just use another extra to determine the previous Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can put data in the intent you use to start this activity. So you can put a different identifier depending on wich "previous" activity started this one. like so :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("PREVIOUS_ACTIVITY", this.getClass().getSimpleName());
startActivity(intent)
```

then you can retrieve this information by doing :
then in the NextActivity, retrieve the values in `onCreate()`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String previous activity= extras.getString("PREVIOUS_ACTIVITY");
}
```

Then you can test the variable and do wathever you want. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences to mark the previous activity:

In on create method of all activities mark the curr activity name in the Shared Preferences and then it's only do the consult.

You can see how to use shared preferences [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)