# Determine Type of Selenium Driver in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on building out a testing framework for some sites using selenium webdriver, and my goal is to have a number of drivers running the same tests concurrently (aka a firefoxdriver, an internetexplorerdriver, and a chromedriver all running at the same time with some shared resources).  However, I'm having trouble with logging which driver is doing what.  I'm passing the drivers through a lot of my code, but as far as I can tell a webdriver has no knowledge of what specific type of driver it is. Is there any way to ask a webdriver element what it was instantiated as?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `instanceof` like

```
  if( driver instanceof FirefoxDriver) {
    System.out.println("Firefox it is!!");
  }
  else if( driver instanceof ChromeDriver) {
    System.out.println("Chrome it is!!");
  }
  // and so on
```

For more details : [What is the 'instanceof' operator used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for)

Comment: Oh my god. *smacks head against desk*. Thanks.

Comment: What if our tests are executing remotely using RemoteWebDriver?

Comment: @san1deep2set3hi use `capabilities.getBrowserName()`

Answer (score 0):

```
/******************************************************************************************
 * Name: getBrowserDetails | Description: Gets Browser Name and Version
 ******************************************************************************************/
public String getBrowserDetails() throws Exception {
    Capabilities caps = ((RemoteWebDriver)BaseTest.driver).getCapabilities();
    String browserName = caps.getBrowserName();
    String browserVersion = caps.getVersion();
    String browser = (browserName + " " + browserVersion).toUpperCase();
    return browser;
}
```

Comment: Could we have some description of how this answers the question?

Comment: This returns you the Browser name , based on the browser name we can decide what type of driver it is

Answer (score 0):

If using `instanceof`, be sure to also consider `org.openqa.selenium.WrapsDriver` so as to handle `EventFiringWebDriver`.