# Java Polymorphism : How can I avoid type casting input parameters?

Tags: java, generics, casting, polymorphism

Assume we have a Parent interface with compare() function.

```
public interface Parent {
    public int compare(Parent otherParent);
}
```

Suppose that children Child1, Child2, Child3 implement this interface Parent

```
public class Child1 implements Parent {
    @Override
    public int compare(Parent other) {
        Child1 otherChild = (Child1)other;
    }
}
```

Also, I am using generics `<T extends Parent>` everywhere else in the code. So I need to compare two objects of type T from other parts of code.

I understand this is a bad design as I am typecasting the Parent object in compare() function and I don't even know whether the input is of type Child1.

How can I avoid this type casting while using generics?

Answer (score 6):

Why not this?

```
interface Parent<T extends Parent<?>> {
    int compare(T type);
}

class Child1 implements Parent<Child1>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Child1 type) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**  To insure correct usage you can use

```
interface Parent<T extends Parent<T>>{ /* ... */ }   //instead of wildcard
```

But to be honest that "loop" doesn't look pretty, and since Generics in Java don't work at RunTime ([more information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)), they're essentially syntactic-sugar for that same cast you called "bad design" so I don't think your current approach is bad.

Comment: The `extends Parent<?>` part indeed does not look pretty. But in fact, it *can* be left out - assuming that the implementor is responsible for using a proper `T`. The same is done in `Comparable`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on how you treat your inheritance hierarchy:

- If derived classes must compare to instances of their own class only, and are allowed to throw an error when presented with object of a different class, use cast, but protect it with checking [`instanceof`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7313559/335858)
- If derived classes must be compared across type boundaries, a more complex strategy is required to avoid casting: you could use a visitor-like pattern to implement double dispatch required to perform the comparison.

Here is a sample implementation using an abstract class:

```
// Use this class as the base class of your Child classes
class AbstractChild implements Parent {
    @Override
    public int compare(Parent otherObj) {
        if (!()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected implementation of Child");
        }
        AbstractChild other = (AbstractChild)otherObj;
        return doCompare(other);
    }
    protected abstract int doCompare(AbstractChild other);
    protected abstract int accept(Child1 c1);
    protected abstract int accept(Child2 c2);
    protected abstract int accept(Child3 c3);
}
class Child1 extends AbstractChild {
    @Override
    protected int doCompare(AbstractChild other) {
         return other.accept(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected int accept(Child1 c1) {
        // Compare c1 instance to this object
    }
    @Override
    protected int accept(Child2 c2) {
        // Compare c2 instance to this object
    }
    @Override
    protected int accept(Child3 c3) {
        // Compare c3 instance to this object
    }
}
class Child2 extends AbstractChild {
    @Override
    protected int doCompare(AbstractChild other) {
         return other.accept(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected int accept(Child1 c1) {
        // Compare c1 instance to this object
    }
    @Override
    protected int accept(Child2 c2) {
        // Compare c2 instance to this object
    }
    @Override
    protected int accept(Child3 c3) {
        // Compare c3 instance to this object
    }
}
class Child3 extends AbstractChild {
    @Override
    protected int doCompare(AbstractChild other) {
         return other.accept(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected int accept(Child1 c1) {
        // Compare c1 instance to this object
    }
    @Override
    protected int accept(Child2 c2) {
        // Compare c2 instance to this object
    }
    @Override
    protected int accept(Child3 c3) {
        // Compare c3 instance to this object
    }
}
```

The only cast in this approach is at the abstract class level. The implementations of the actual comparison logic are contained in `accept` methods, where the comparison is done between two objects of known type.

Comment: I must admit that I'm at a bit of a loss about the advantage of having this code compared to having in-method type castin/checking. I've not been overly much of a Java expert the last decade (when did Java 1.4 come out? since then), so: Is letting the JVM do the type comparisons necessary to "delegate" to the right method really of any performance merit or has other advantages (aside from probably being "the right thing to do", letting a strongly typed language handle type disambiguation)?

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is an answer to the question "how do you avoid cast", which assumes that you want to avoid it for some reason. I have used similar approach in the past in very specific situations, when I could leverage the visitor for something more than comparison. I have transitioned from Java to C# around the time when Java-5 came out, and I used a different language mechanism to implement my multiple dispatch there (namely, `dynamic`, which is available since C# 4).

Comment: Agreeing with my comment being a bit off-topic :) Clearly, the visitor pattern is *the* classical approach to recovering type information lost by passing things around in a polymorphic language that's kind of limited in cleanly dealing with different type information objects (comparing Java to C#, or even dynamically typed scripting languages like Python, where I could actually use types as key to a dict of callables, if I wanted to). My hope simply was that you could shine a bit of experience on this, which you did :) thanks!

Comment: Is `if (!()) { ... }` syntactically correct, or is it a *pseudo code* place holder of sorts? My IDE is complaining about it. I'm not trying to point out any possible mistake, I was just wondering if this is a Java feature that I've never seen before.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Java Interfaces are exactly what the name implies – an interface dictating the types accepted; so there needs to be *exactly* the same method signature at compile time as defined in the interface.

Yes, casting this back to a Child type feels like bad design – but it's really the bad design that Java dictates, so that's not your fault.

Comment: Guess I will have to use type-cast then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid it in the general case. However, if the number of child classes is fixed, you can apply something akin to the visitor pattern to avoid casting at the expense of writing more code:

```
interface Parent {
   int compare(Parent p);
   protected int compareWith(Child1 c);
   protected int compareWith(Child2 c);
   protected int compareWith(Child3 c);
}

class Child1 implements Parent {
    @Override int compare(Parent p) {
        return p.compareWith(this);
    }
    @Override int compareWith(Child1 c) {
       //specific code to child1
    }
    @Override int compareWith(Child2 c) {
       //specific code to child2
    }
    @Override int compareWith(Child3 c) {
       //specific code to child3
    }
}
// and so on for the other children
```

This does avoid casting, but I'm not sure the extra effort is worth it in the case you presented here.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern that you described there is **exactly** the pattern of [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). In fact, you should consider omitting your `Parent` interface, and replace it with `Comparable` instead.

The `Comparable` interface and its uses also show how this can be solved: The type can be given as a parameter, to make sure that only the matching type can be passed to the `compare` method:

```
interface Parent<T> {
    int compare(T that);
}

class Child1 implements Parent<Child1> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Child1 that) {
        ...
    }
}
```

For all other cases, you would at least have to think about what should happen when different `Child`-classes are compared to each other:

```
Child1 c1 = new Child1();
Child2 c2 = new Child2();

// Should this be possible? What should happen here? 
// How should different child classes be compared?
c1.compare(c2);
```