# About inheritance of java

Tags: java

/**
 * Created by zhangzhongzheng on 2016/10/15.
 */

public class ExtendsTest {

```
static Dog d = new Dog();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal a = d;
    System.out.println(a instanceof Animal);//true
    System.out.println(a instanceof Dog);//true

    System.out.println(d instanceof Animal);//true
    System.out.println(d instanceof Dog);//true
}

static class Animal {

}

static class Dog extends Animal {

}
```

}

why all true??????

Comment: There are three here that should be slap-in-the-face obvious and the other is too if you take a little time to investigate [`instanceof`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for) or just consider the name slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In keeping with the concept of type,instanceos says,"Are you this class,or a class derived from this class?"-------<>

Answer (score 0):

Here Animal is a Parent and Dog is a child.

Parent class reference can hold child class object.

Animal animal = new Dog();

So all above conditions are true.