# How to proof if an object is an imageview?

Tags: java, android, object

I want to remove all imageviews on a relative layout in Android Studio, save them and replace them later.

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
ArrayList al = rl.getTouchables();
rl.removeAllViews();
//do something
for(int i=0; i<al.size(); i++) 
{
 if(al.get(i).equals(new ImageView(this))) 
 rl.addView((ImageView) al.get(i));
}
```

The programm is not working :(

Comment: instanceof? ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for

Answer (score 2):

Find all the image views in the viewgroup using `instanceof`. Once you have them all, remove the images from the viewgroup. Then you can do whatever work you need to do on these images:

```
final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
final List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
    final View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
    if (v instanceof ImageView) {
        images.add((ImageView) v);
    }
}
for (final ImageView v : images) {
    vg.removeView(v);
}
```

When java 8 rolls around I imagine we'd be able to do something like this:

```
final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
final List<ImageView> images = IntStream()
    .range(0, vg.getChildCount())
    .mapToObj(vg::getChildAt)
    .filter(ImageView.class::isInstance)
    .map(ImageView.class::cast)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
images.stream().forEach(vg::removeView);
```