# Java Returning Type of Child class (abstract)

Tags: java

I've been trying my best with some basic code, and I am completely stuck...

I have an abstract class "Piece":

```
public abstract class Piece {
    private static int type;

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

The "Pawn" is the Child:

```
public class Pawn extends Piece {
    private static final int type = 1;
}
```

And now for the problem: When creating the Pawn with `Pawn p = new Pawn();`, `p.getType()` returns `0`, not `1`...
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you already have a variable declared in your abstract class. You shouldn't redeclare it in your subclass. Instead, set the abstract class's variable like this:

```java
public class Pawn extends Piece {
    public Pawn() {
        type = 1;
    }
}
```

You should also declare the variable as `protected` so that subclasses can access it and refrain from making it `static`, since that will allow only one value for all subclasses:

```java
public abstract class Piece {
    protected int type;

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.  But you really need to read up on classes and abstract classes.

```java
public abstract class Piece {
   public int getType() {
      return 0;
   }
}

public class Pawn extends Piece {
    public int getType() {
        return 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: I think one improvement would be to make the `getType` method itself abstract in `Piece`, like `public abstract int getType();`. That makes it where the compiler requires you to redefine it for each piece type, saving you from forgetting to replace the default in a piece type.

Comment: Just having a getType() method is probably bad and the author needs to learn more about OOP.

Answer (score 1):

This code you write relies on an instance and not on a static context:

```
Pawn p = new Pawn();
p.getType();
```

A static final field is not designed to be inherited by child classes.

And creating a static final field in the child class with the same name as in the parent class doesn't allow to override it either.

1) So you should use an instance field and not a static field for the `type` field.

2) If you want to override the behavior of getType() in the child class, in fact you don't even need to use a field. Using a method should be enough.

In the base class :

```
public abstract class Piece {

  public int getType() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

In the child class :

```
public class Pawn extends Piece {
    @Override
    public int getType() {
       return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a static variable in a class means that all instances of that class share the same value. I don't think that's what you intended.

Also, you can use the hierarchy of inheritance to your advantage by not redefining the `getType()` method.

Here is one of many ways to solve it:

```
public abstract class Piece {
    protected int type;

    public int getType() {
      return type;
    }
}

public class Pawn extends Piece {
    public Pawn() {
        type = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was the first, but it often happens.

Answer (score -1):

There are two problems with your approach.

The first is that Java does not support inheritance of static methods. Not that it couldn't have supported this - it's just a design choice. What this means is that any method of class `Piece`, which calls `getType()` - calls the `Piece` class' implementation of `getType()`, not a polymorphic call to `getType()` of whatever the actual subclass is.

The second problem is that you're sort of reinventing the wheel. Java has rich reflection facilities: You can use [getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) and [`instanceof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for) for your check:

```
if(myObject instanceof Piece && myObject.getClass() != Piece.class) {
    // do stuff
}
```

and of course you can make this a method of the piece class (no need to override it).