# Why both subclass and superclass are true while using instanceof?

Tags: java, interface

Sorry that I had a mistake while posting. The class that implements I should be B rather than A in this case. And here it is where I find confusing. 
Also, if it is class C that implements I rather than A or B, the results are still the same.

```
interface I{}

public class A{
    A() {
        System.out.print("A: " + (this instanceof I) + " ");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new C();
    }
}

class B extends A implements I {
    B() {
        System.out.print("B: " + (this instanceof I) + " ");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    C() {
        System.out.print("C: " + (this instanceof I) + " ");
    }
}
```

Why both **subclass** and **superclass** are `true` while using `instanceof`?

The result of this code is:

```
A: true
B: true
C: true
```

Comment: `Classes can be derived from classes that are derived from classes that are derived from classes, and so on, and ultimately derived from the topmost class, Object. Such a class is said to be descended from all the classes in the inheritance chain stretching back to Object.`  - Java Documentation

Comment: See [What is the 'instanceof' operator used for in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for-in-java)

Comment: For completeness: [Oracle's tutorial on Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Comment: Cats are a "subclass" of animal; tigers are a subclass of cat.  But Tigers are still both Cats and Animals, yes?  It's the same whether the Animals, Cats and Tigers are living beings or Java classes.

Comment: This is a basic tenet of OOP. See [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score 4):

The `instanceof` operator checks whether the given object is a **sublcass** (not necessarily a *true subclass*) of the given class. This does in general mean that you can **cast** the object to that class (reduce the view to it).

So for example if we have an `ArrayList` we could cast it to `List`, also `instanceof` would return `true` if we check that `ArrayList` against `List`. So in your example of course you could do

```
new C() instanceof B // true
new B() instanceof A // true
```

However the classes also **inherit** such properties from their parents. Thus the class `C` is of course **also** subclass of `A`, since it is subclass of `B` and `B` is subclass of `A`, so we get

```
new C() instanceof A // true
```

And the same holds for **interfaces** too, we get

```
new A() instanceof I // true
```

and by **inheritance**

```
new B() instanceof I // true
new C() instanceof I // true
```

---

### Practical example

Take a look at the following example

```
public interface CanBark { }

public class Dog implements CanBark { }

public class Pug extends Dog { }
```

of course the `Pug` is a `Dog` and since `Dog` is a `CanBark` the `Pug` is also a `CanBark`, we get

```
new Pug() instanceof Dog     // true
new Dog() instanceof CanBark // true
new Pug() instanceof CanBark // true
```

---

### Details of `instanceof`

The **Java Language Specification** ([§15.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)) defines the behavior of the `instanceof` operator as

> At run time, the result of the `instanceof` operator is `true` if the value of the *RelationalExpression* is **not** `null` and the reference could be `cast` ([§15.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)) to the *ReferenceType* without raising a `ClassCastException`. Otherwise the result is `false`.

Whereas the `cast` ([§15.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)) behaves like

> [...] or checks, at run time, that a *reference value* refers to an object whose *class* is **compatible** with a specified *reference type*.

Therefore the casting refers to the **casting rules** specified in ([§5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5)). Your specific case is defined in ([§5.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1)) as

> If `T` (target) is an **interface** type:
>   If `S` (source) is not a final class ([§8.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1)), then, if there exists a supertype `X` of `T`, and a supertype `Y` of `S`, such that both `X` and `Y` are **provably distinct parameterized types**, and that the **erasures** of `X` and `Y` **are the same**, a **compile-time error** occurs.
>   **Otherwise**, the cast is **always legal** at compile time (because even if `S` does not implement `T`, a subclass of `S` might).

Answer (score 1):

This is a fundamental of object oriented programming. Let me give you an example which might help you to feel why subclasses get the behavior of interfaces implemented by parent class. Let me know if this helps.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

interface Flyable {
    /* Guys, Don't worry about what kind of flyable object you are talking to. 
     * just call me if you want to request someone to fly. */
    public void fly();

}

/*
 * Bird is abstract since there is nothing called 'Bird' existing in the world.
 * It should be either a Crow, Pegion, Sparrow and so on.
 */

abstract class Bird implements Flyable {

    public void fly() {
    /*  All birds follow same sequence of actions to fly.
     This method contains set of instructions to fly. */
    }

    // call this method to know where the bird was born
    public abstract String getCountry();
}


class Sparrow extends Bird {

    private String country;

    // I am responsible to give birth to a new sparrow.
    Sparrow(String beakColor, int weight, String bodyColor, String countryToLive) {
        this.country = countryToLive;

        // code to give birth to a new sparrow.
    }

    // Call me to know where i'm born
    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }


}

class Helicopter implements Flyable {

    private Date manufacturDate;
    private int engineCapacity;

    Helicopter() {
        /* sequence of instruction on how to assemble a new helicopter with default specifications */
    }

    @Override
    public void fly() {
        /* sequence of instruction on how helicopter should fly
         * Of course it will be different from how birds fly
         *  */

    }

    public Date getManufacturDate() {
        return this.manufacturDate;
    }

    public int getEngineCapacity() {
        return this.engineCapacity;
    }

}


class RandomSkyObjectsHandler {

    public static List<Flyable> getFewFlyableObjectsOfAnyType() {
        List<Flyable> randomList = new ArrayList<Flyable>();
        Sparrow sp1 = new Sparrow("black", 50, "brown", "India");
        Helicopter h1 = new Helicopter();
        Helicopter h2 = new Helicopter();
        Sparrow sp2 =  new Sparrow("Brown", 60, "white", "Kenya");
        Helicopter h3 = new Helicopter();
        Sparrow sp3 = new Sparrow("white", 70, "black", "USA");

        Flyable[] f = {sp1, sp2, h1, sp3, h2, h3};
        randomList = Arrays.asList(f);
        return randomList;


    }
}


public class TestProgramExecutor {
    public static void main(String... commandLineArguments) {

        List<Flyable> mixOfFlyingStuff = RandomSkyObjectsHandler.getFewFlyableObjectsOfAnyType();

        /* here is the beauty of OOPS. I don't need the knowledge of whether i'm telling a helicopter to fly or a sparrow to fly.
         * I'm just pretty sure that I'm talking to a flyable object and it understand if i say fly();
         * */

        for(Flyable f: mixOfFlyingStuff) {

            f.fly();
        }
    }
}
```