# Cast fails when casting a sub class equals to the super class

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception

I am a little confuse on why the below code doesn't work and throw a ClassCastException:

```
Person superPerson = new Person("marc", 18);        

        PersonOverwritten subPerson = (PersonOverwritten) superPerson;      
        System.out.println(subPerson);
```

Where the subclass is the same as the super:

```
public class PersonOverwritten extends Person {

    public PersonOverwritten(String nome, int idade) {
        super();
    }

}
```

Of course it should fail if they are from different types, but, why this doesn't work?

Comment: Because not every dog is a dachshound...

Comment: A `PersonOverwritten` is a `Person`, but a `Person` is not necessarily a `PersonOverwritten`, and in this case, is not.

Comment: Yet another question that is answered with article from the language specification. This type of casting is called [Narrowing reference conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6), and there are perfectly clear rules that instruct what cases work and why.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple example to illustrate. Imagine that `PersonOverwritten` looked like this:

```
public class PersonOverwritten extends Person {
    public PersonOverwritten(String nome, int idade) {
        super();
    }
    public void pickupSticks() {}
}
```

Very clearly you would not be able to do

```
Person superPerson = new Person("marc", 18);        
PersonOverwritten subPerson = (PersonOverwritten) superPerson;
subPerson.pickupSticks();
```

because the object assigned to `subPerson` does not have the `pickupSticks` method.

The reason that the compiler allows you to write code like that, though, is that you might one day want to do something like this:

```
Person person = new PersonOverwritten("marc", 18);        
((PersonOverwritten)person).pickupSticks();
```

In this case, there will of course not be a runtime error, because the object that you have assigned to `person` *does* support the extended interface. A very common place to see something like that was before generics were introduced in Java 1.5, and all the collections returned `Object` when you accessed them.

**Update**

To elaborate a bit, Java uses types to determine the contract that an object fulfills, rather than a direct inspection of the attributes. It does not use duck-typing, like say Python. The compiler will allow you to cast `Person` to `PersonOverwritten` because it *might* be possible. The runtime will forbid you from using an actual `Person` object as a `PersonOverwritten` because, according to Java, it does not fulfill the interface.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I get this concept that not necessarily the person is-a personOverwritten, but is this case it is and do have the same methods, so why it still doesn't work?

Comment: Because Java doesn't compare the contents for deciding the "is-a" relation, but looks at the class inheritance tree. Other languages might behave differently...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast `new Person()` to `PersonOverwritten`.

Although the compiler will let this pass, the runtime will detect that the type `Person` is too broad to fit into `PersonOverwritten`, which is why you get that `ClassCastException`.

---

Just a side note: A similar exception would occur if you had a different, unrelated subclass of the same parent:

```
public class AnotherPersonOverwritten extends Person {}
```

The following is also incorrect:

```
Person subPerson = new AnotherPersonOverwritten();
PersonOverwritten personOverwritten = (PersonOverwritten) new subPerson;
//class cast exception
```

**How do you avoid this**: Make sure that the runtime class of the object being cast (the class with which the `new` keyword is used, in this case) is the same as or the subclass of the class to which the object is being cast.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an object of parent class to its subclass reference variable will fail. As **#Turing85** and **#rgettman** mentioned in the comment.

Look at the following code:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
// Cat cat = new Cat();
// Animal animal = cat;
Animal animal = dog; // here upcasting is automatic
if(animal instanceof Dog) // only if the animal is of type Dog
    Dog dogDup = (Dog) animal; // manual downcasting
/* 
Animal animal = new Animal();
Dog dog = (Dog) animal; // this won't work
*/
```

See the full article [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~cannata/cs345/Class%20Notes/14%20Java%20Upcasting%20Downcasting.htm)

To prevent your code from throwing runtime exception, use instanceof operator like this

```
Person superPerson = new Person("marc", 18);
if(superPerson instanceof PersonOverwritten) // in this case it's "false"
    PersonOverwritten subPerson = (PersonOverwritten) superPerson;
```

[for more details refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for-in-java) stackoverflow question]

Hope this will help!