# How to compare objects by property

Tags: java

I have an object called `Product` and I want to check if a user-entered string matches the name of one of the `Product`s.

I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```java
Product  laptop = new Product(1, "Laptop", "Type", 1350.25, "black");
Product  mouse = new Product(2, "Mouse", "Type", 50.50, "black");

String check = new String("laptop");

if (check.equals(instanceof Product))  
{
    System.out.println("Yes it is.");
}
    else
{
    System.out.println("No, it is not.");
}
```

Comment: That's wrong on so many levels. What do you want help with.

Comment: The purpose of `instanceOf` is to check if a instance is of a specified class.

Comment: Create a collection of all `Product` instances, iterate over that and for each element check wether or not the `name` (or whatever) contains the search term.

Comment: Your examples show that you lack the fundamentals or programming. I would recommend you find a good tutorial which comes with homework examples and work through that tutorial (while completing **every** example faithfully).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a `name` variable in your `Product` class. So what you would want to do is compare the `name` variable to the String. Something like this:

```
private String name;
Product  laptop = new Product(1, "Laptop", "Type", 1350.25, "black");
Product  mouse = new Product(2, "Mouse", "Type", 50.50, "black");

String check = new String("laptop");
if(check.equals(laptop.getName()) {
    System.out.println("Match!");
} else {
    System.out.println("No match...");
}
```

Here's a good SO discussion about the proper use of `instanceof`:

[What is the 'instanceof' operator used for in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for-in-java)