# How to find if my object extends a given abstract class ?

Tags: java

I have the main class

```
public class Main(){
   public static void main(String[] args){
      ArrayList<A> as = new ArrayList<>();
      C c = new C();
      D d = new D();
      E e = new E();

      as.add(c);
      as.add(d);
      as.add(e);

      for(A a : as){
         a.print(); // want to do it conditionally when Object inside list have extended class B
      }
   }
}
```

Method print() is extended from an abstract class A.
Classes C and D extends class B and B extends A.

```
    A
  /   \
  B    E
 / \
C   D
```

How can I do this approach?

Tried:

```
for(A a : as){
   if(a.getClass().getSuperclass().getSimpleName().equals("B")){
      a.print(); // Doesn't work a.getClass().getSuperclass().getSimpleName() prints A
   }
}
```

Any tip to achieve this?

Comment: use instanceof as in `if (a instanceof B)`

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve with this (i.e. why do you need the class name)? Having to use `instanceof` could mean that the design needs improving.

Comment: When you have a problem, try to find the real source of problem, it's not "get the name of an abstract parent class", but "know if an object extends a class ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `instanceof`:

```
for(A a : as){
    if(a instanceof B){
        a.print();
    }
}
```

For more information see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for-in-java).

Comment: Thanks, it works near perfect, but dunno why prints twice each method.