# How to access a derived class member variable by an interface object in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, extends, implements

I am a new java programmer.

I have following hierarchy of classes:

```
public interface base

public interface Object1Type extends base

public interface Object2Type extends Object1Type

public class Object3Type implements Object2Type
{ 
      byte[] value;
}
```

I have another class where I have an object of Object1Type a;

can I access byte[] value member of Object3Type type using this object a?

Comment: You would have to cast to `Object3Type`

Comment: It is not a good practice for parents to know about children and siblings to know about each other.

Comment: You *shouldn't*. If you need to know about the fact that `value` exists, then your code needs to express that need by using the correct type. In some cases, it might be appropriate to define an extra interface `HasValue` to represent this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [class cast](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Object1Type a = new Object3Type();

    if (a instanceof Object3Type) {
        Object3Type b = (Object3Type) a;
        byte[] bytes = b.value;
    }
}
```

But it's dangerous and not recommended practice. The responsibility for cast correctness lies on a programmer. See example:

```
class Object3Type implements Object2Type {
    byte[] value;
}

class Object4Type implements Object2Type {
    byte[] value;
}

class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Object1Type a = new Object3Type();

        Object3Type b = (Object3Type) a; // Compiles and works without exceptions
        Object4Type c = (Object4Type) a; // java.lang.ClassCastException: Object3Type cannot be cast to Object4Type
    }
}
```

If you do it, at least check an object with the [instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for-in-java) operator previously.

I'll recommend you to declare some getter in one of the interfaces (existing or new) and implement this method in the class:

```
interface Object1Type extends Base {
    byte[] getValue();
}

interface Object2Type extends Object1Type {}

class Object3Type implements Object2Type {
    byte[] value;

    public byte[] getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Object1Type a = new Object3Type();
        byte[] bytes = a.getValue();
    }
}
```