# Attempting to access a method in another class

Tags: java

So im tring to write a section of code that cycles through a linked list which contains different instances of a class, picks out instances with a specific ID, runs a method contained within that instance class and changes a variable which is specific to that instance. However, I cannot seem to access the methods contained within the given object. Any ideas on how to access methods from other classes?

```
public void tick() {
    for(int i=0; i < handler.object.size() ;i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
        if (tempObject.getId() == ID.FlashCardCover){
            //run a method in FlashCardCover class on this individual object
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: No one will be in any position to help you unless you post complete code.

Comment: It's not even clear to me what you mean by *"run a method in FlashCardCover class on this individual object"*. What method are you trying to call?  Where is it defined? Is it `static` or instance-based? If the latter, do you have an instance of that object?  What specifically do you try and how specifically does it fail?  If you're just asking how to call a method, well, where do you call this `tick()` method? However you're doing that, that's how you call a method. You're also successfully calling the methods `size()` and `get(int)` and `getId()` in this code. Those are how you call a method.

Comment: Does FlashCardCover extend or implement GameObject? Is tempObject an instance of FlashCardCover because is has that ID? If so, then cast tempObject to FlashCardCover and you will be able to call the method.

Comment: Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your post accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code:

```
public void tick() {
    for(int i=0; i < handler.object.size() ;i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
        if (tempObject.getId() == ID.FlashCardCover){
            //run a method in FlashCardCover class on this individual object
        }
    }   
}
```

If I interpret this correctly, you have some `GameObject`s and one of the kinds of GameObject is a `FlashCardCover`. You determine this by checking the "Id" (which I would call "TypeId" or just "Type")

So as you loop through your GameObjects, you want to call some method when that particular GameObject is in fact a FlashCardCover.  You would do that by invoking the method on that object, say like `tempObject.uncoverCard()` — but of course you can't do that because a GameObject doesn't have an *uncoverCard* method.
This is where you use a [cast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Explicit_type_conversion)

```
public void tick()
{
    for (int i=0; i<handler.object.size(); i++)
    {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
        if (tempObject.getId() == ID.FlashCardCover) {
            FlashCardCover c = (FlashCardCover) tempObject;
            c.uncoverCard();
        }
    }   
}
```

You have cast the `tempObject` to be a `FlashCardCover` and *that* is an object on which you can call your "uncoverCard" method.
The cast doesn't have to be done in two lines (I did that for clarity) -- you can cast and call at the same time, such as `((FlashCardCover) tempObject).uncoverCard()`

Note that this all assumes that FlashCardCover is a subclass of GameObject, e.g.

```
public class FlashCardCover extends GameObject { ... }
```

If it doesn't you'll get a [`ClassCastException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)

Now with all that explained ... you don't need your own type codes to do this sort of casting, you can use [`instanceof`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7313559/17300) instead.

```
if (tempObject instanceof FlashCardCover) {
    // do your thing
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Despite my poor description of the problem you managed to find a solution to it. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Answer to above comments is important to answer your question correctly, going by your comment in code snippet "*run a method in FlashCardCover class on this individual object*" looks like **GameObject** extents or implements **FlashCardCover**, if that assumption is correct then tempObject.invoke(...) , with all required parameters to this should do the trick assuming this method is visible.