# Convert from Object type data to int type data in java

Tags: object, char, type-conversion, int

So, I had a quiz yesterday and I was given an Object type array with both int and char type elements(as below). I had to create a custom Linked List class and create a LinkedList using only the characters from the array. The problem which a faced was I could not differentiate between char and int as it was all 'Object' type. How can you convert an element from Object to an int or char? thanks a lot.
the array I was given :

```
Objects[] array={1,32,c,f,16,-1,g,25,m,k};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
myVar instanceOf Integer
```

to check if your variable is an Integer or a Character then you can cast your variable to the selected type

```
Integer myInt = (Integer) myVar;
```

More info here : [What is the 'instanceof' operator used for in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for-in-java)