# Mongodb polymorphism Java object unable to determine concrete class

Tags: java, mongodb, polymorphism, micronaut

I am using Mongodb with Micronaut and reading polymorphic Java object gives me error because Mongodb is unable to determine the concrete implementation class by its type.

```
myPet: { "_id" : ObjectId("5f96f4633dbd690c548c2a38"), pets: [{"type" : "Cat" }, {"type" : "Dog" }]}

public class MyPet {
  private List<Animal> pets = new ArrayList<Animal>(0);

  public List<Animal> getPets() {
    return pets;
  }

  public void setPets(List<Animal> pets) {
    this.pets = pets;
  }
}

public class Cat implements Animal {
  private String type = "Cat";

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}

public class Dog implements Animal {
  private String type = "Dog";

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}

public interface Animal {
  String getType();
}
```

I tried

```
MongoCollection<MyPet> myPetColl = db.getCollection("myPet", MyPet.class);
myPetColl.find()
```

but get below error

```
Unexpected error occurred: An exception occurred when decoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
Decoding into a 'MyPet' failed with the following exception:

Failed to decode 'MyPet'. Decoding 'content' errored with: Cannot find a public constructor for 'Animal'.

A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and registered to handle this type.
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: An exception occurred when decoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
Decoding into a 'MyPet' failed with the following exception:

Failed to decode 'MyPet'. Decoding 'content' errored with: Cannot find a public constructor for 'Animal'.

A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and registered to handle this type.
        at org.bson.codecs.pojo.AutomaticPojoCodec.decode(AutomaticPojoCodec.java:40)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandResultArrayCodec.decode(CommandResultArrayCodec.java:52)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:60)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
        at org.bson.internal.LazyCodec.decode(LazyCodec.java:48)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.readValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:101)
        at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandResultDocumentCodec.readValue(CommandResultDocumentCodec.java:63)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:84)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:41)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ReplyMessage.<init>(ReplyMessage.java:51)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.getCommandResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:412)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$900(InternalStreamConnection.java:75)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:397)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:375)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:676)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:643)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:513)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:510)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:230)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:213)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:158)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:560)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:277)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:298)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$AsynchronousSocketChannelAdapter.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:136)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream.readAsync(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:109)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.readAsync(InternalStreamConnection.java:510)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$1000(InternalStreamConnection.java:75)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:633)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:618)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:513)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:510)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:230)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:213)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:437)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:191)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.KQueuePort$EventHandlerTask.run(KQueuePort.java:312)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Is there a way to return the correct class type with if-condition:

if (obj.type == "Dog") return Dog.class else Cat.class

like in Jackson

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "Dog"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "Cat"),
})
```

Comment: Im not experienced with the database, but the answer to `if (obj.type == "Dog")` is [instanceof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@BsonDiscriminator` annotation to tell MongoDB driver which field is used as a discriminator key. Here is a working example:

```java
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.annotations.BsonDiscriminator;

@BsonDiscriminator(key = Animal.DISCRIMINATOR_KEY)
public interface Animal {
    String DISCRIMINATOR_KEY = "type";

    String getType();
}

public class Cat implements Animal {
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return Cat.class.getName();
    }
}

public class Dog implements Animal {
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return Dog.class.getName();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using full class name as a value for `type` field. Unfortunately custom discriminator values (different then full class name) does not work yet in Micronaut MongoDB Client now. It is because of this issue, which still not solved: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-mongodb/issues/10