# Which is the equivalent of "isinstance" (Python) for Java?

Tags: java, python, isinstance

I have a program to generate requests to test Apis, the next part of the code reads a JSON to manage the info of the values later:

```
def recorre_llaves(self, dicc):
    campos = []
    for k in dicc.keys():
        if isinstance(dicc[k], dict):
            for e in self.recorre_llaves(dicc[k]):
                campos.append(e)
        elif isinstance(dicc[k], list):
            if isinstance(dicc[k][0], dict):
                for e in self.recorre_llaves(dicc[k][0]):
                    campos.append(e)
                pass
            else:
                campos.append(Campo(k, dicc[k][0]))
        else:
            campos.append(Campo(k, dicc[k]))
        pass
    return campos
    pass
```

The program iterates over the JSON and creates new objects with the key and the value. Now I need to do the same but using Java and I'm having problems with the method "isInstance()" I want to do something like:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;    
HashMap <String, Object> response = mapper.readValue(request, HashMap.class);    
HashMap.get("KEY").isInstance();
```

But it doesn't works, Do you know a way to do the same with Java?

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` in Python corresponds to `List` in Java (see the [javadoc of `java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)).
And `dict` in Python corresponds to `Map` in Java (see the [javadoc of `java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)).

The Python function `isinstance` corresponds to the Java key-word `instanceof`.

Hence the Python line

```
if isinstance(dicc[k], dict):
```

would be written in Java like this:

```
if (dicc.get(k) instanceof List)
```

Answer (score 0):

instanceof returns a boolean

Simple1 s=new Simple1();
System.out.println(s instanceof Simple1);//true