# RecyclerView different action from different fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-navigation

I have 3 `Fragments` A, B, and C. The fragment in B contain a `Recyclerview` (list of items), and I have a link from A-to->B and from C-to->B, which means I can reach the fragment B from both destinations A and C.  **(A)-->**B**<--(C)**. What do I want, if I came from A->B and I clicked on an item in the list I will have action different from the action if I came from C->B.

Comment: identify in B parent fragment instance A or C and take actions, for more on instance of more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for-in-java

Comment: how you are using click callback with interface or direct into recyclerView

Comment: I'm using CallBack with interface