# Create a list with only base class elements

Tags: java, collections

In Java I have a class

```
Foo {
    String a;
}
```

and subclass

```
Bar extends Foo {
    String b;
}
```

Now let's say I have `List<Bar> bars`.

How can I create from this a `List` of `Foo` (and I only want the `a` field to appear, not `b`)

Comment: `bars.stream().map(Foo.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Use instanceof, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is impossible; let's say you have your `bars` list which contains 5 Bar instances.

It is **not possible** in java to convert Bar instances to Foo instances; nothing in the language lets you do this. You can of course program it (e.g. that `Foo` has this cloning constructor:

```
class Foo {
  String a;

  public Foo(Foo toClone) {
    this.a = toClone.a;
  }
}
```

But the point is: You'd have to write that, the language will not do it for you.

The way subclassing works: All Bars are also Foos. So, you can do this:

```
Bar b = new Bar(...);
Foo clone = new Foo(b);
```

Which will 'work' - 'b' is of type Bar which is fine when invoking a method or constructor that wants a Foo, as Bar is a subtype of Foo.

If you want to treat your list as Foos instead, feel free:

```
List<Bar> bars = List.of(bar1, bar2, bar3);
List<? extends Foo> foos = bars;
```

And `foos.get(0)` will be an expression of type `Foo` (not Bar), and thus java won't let you call things on whatever `foos.get(0)` returns that only Bar has. However, make no mistake, `foos.get(0)` **still returns a Bar instance**:

```
Foo f = foos.get(0);
System.out.println(f.getClass()); // prints 'Bar'
System.out.println(f instanceof Bar); // Returns 'true'
```

It sounds like you're slightly confused about subclassing.