# Why does instanceof and addition get executed in the wrong order?

Tags: java, operator-precedence

When I simply write the code

```
String x = null;

System.out.println(x instanceof Object);
```

The output is `false`, as expected.

But when I try to write it slightly different, namely as:

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = null;
        System.out.println("Result is: " + x instanceof Object);
    
  }
}
```

I get `true` as output. Why?

`x instanced Object` should still be `false`, no? I would like to get an output like

```
Result is: false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the 'instanceof' operator used for in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313559/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-used-for-in-java)

Comment: Put braces around the `x instanceof Object` and try again.

Comment: @deHaar no it doesn't work like that. I want to print like this -Result is::  false where false is the value of x instanced Object. Instead my codes prints true...which I don't understand why

Comment: @Turamarth No it doesn't. I want it to print like this - Result is:: false where false is the value of x instanced Object. Instead my codes prints true...which I don't understand why

Comment: @maloomeister I am not assuming ...since string x is pointing to null... x instance of Object is false for a null object. That is why it should be false...if I simply print System.out.println(x instanceof Object); it will come false...but when I try to format it the way I did in my question I get true as output...which is confusing. I know I am doing some silly mistake as I am a newbie and learning but I am not able to figure out my mistake

Comment: @AdityaPatel So did you actually put braces around like it was suggested? -> `System.out.println("Result is:: " + (x instanceof Object));` You say that you did, but it seems like you didn't, otherwise you would get the results you expect.

Comment: Downvoted and voting to close because you have not explained **why** you think it should be `false`. Because of that, it is impossible to answer your question without guessing. It is lacking details and is unclear, unfortunately.

Comment: Good edit. Reversing my actions.

Answer (score 10):

### Why is it `true`?

Java evaluates your code in a different order than you might expect. When you write

```java
System.out.println("Result is: " + x instanceof Object);
```

what Java executes is:

1. String concatenation `"Result is: " + x` resulting in the string `"Result is: null`, then
2. checking that string against `instanceof Object`, so `"Result is: null" instanceof Object` which is obviously `true`.

I.e. it executes it as if you would put paranthesis like this:

```java
System.out.println(("Result is: " + x) instanceof Object);
```

This is due to the operator precedence rules in Java, which you can read more about here: [Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

You can see that addition `+` binds stronger than `instanceof`:

[image: Precedence table]

### How to get the expected output?

In order to get the expected output, you have to make the order explicit by using paranthesis as follows:

```java
System.out.println("Result is: " + (x instanceof Object));
// Result is: false
```

alternatively, split the expression into multiple by using some variables:

```java
boolean isObject = x instanceof Object;
System.out.println("Result is: " + isObject);
```

Arguably also more readable.

As a general note, never rely on operator precedence rules (unless maybe `*` and `+` in a math context), otherwise you will only confuse readers.